# Android shared elements transition pre-21

Tags: android, android-activity, shared-element-transition, activity-transition

How can I implement shared elements transitions in pre-21 devices?
I've more or less followed the guide here http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/ but I get errors like "attribute transitionName only used in api level 21 or higher"

Comment: Yep, looks like a duplicate. Didn't see that before

Answer (score 14):

There is no compatibility libraries that support shared element transitions. The best you can do is use the approach described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA)... however, note that it takes a lot more code to implement.

Comment: That's unfortunate...
Do you have any idea if google is planning on rolling out support any time soon? Looks like they have the transitions in their own applications already

Comment: Last time I heard there are no plans to provide a support library for shared element transitions... there are too many features that were added in Lollipop that shared element transitions depend on for a well-written library to provide. For example, shared element transitions between Activities is not possible in previous versions of the platform since they depend on the Render Thread which was only added in Lollipop.

Comment: @AlexLockwood, there must be some trick!
Cos in my 4.4 device in gmail app - there are shared element transition(or some trick!), when i am clicking on some email its title slide to title of the next fragment ;-)

Comment: @LudoBagman I'm guessing the gmail app probably wrote their own animation framework to support pre-Lollipop devices.